# Does canon EOS 1000D support video recording?

Tags: dslr, video

I want to buy an entry level DSLR and EOS 1000D seems like a good buy but I have some doubts regarding it. Does it support video recording?

Do I need to install some software for the video recording to work? If yes, does that record the videos with sound? If no, how can I record video with sound on the Canon EOS 1000D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot officially record video, but there is an [open source project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eos-movrec) to allow recording direct to a computer.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_1000D)

Given that it doesn't support video natively then there won't be a built in microphone to record sound. If you went with the open source software you'd have to record the sound separately and sync it afterwards - which is not a straightforward process.

Comment: It should be said that trying to separately record sound and afterwards syncing it to the video is difficult. Unless one has done it before and has the equipment to record sound separately it would also be cheaper to pay more for a Canon 1100D, which does support video recording, IIRC.

Comment: @Unapiedra Thanks! One more thing: Does 1100D allow you to adjust focus when the shooting is on? I read that some cameras lock the focus once the shooting starts.